# 3-divergence of vorticity vector in GR

Tags: general-relativity, fluid-dynamics, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, vortex

In *Relativistic Cosmologies* (Ellis, Maartens, MacCallum), the authors claim that (page 86, section 4.7)
$$
\overline{\omega^i{}_{;i}} = \omega^i\dot{u}_i.\tag{A}
$$
Here $u_i$ is a timelike vector field, $\dot{u}_i := u_{i;j}u^j$ is the acceleration, and the vorticity $\omega_{ij} := h_i{}^kh_j{}^\ell u_{[k;\ell]}$ has been defined, where $h^{ij} := u^iu^j + g^{ij}$ is the projection operator relative to $u^i$ (spacelike signature convention) and brackets indicate anti-symmetrization. Then $\omega^i := -\frac{1}{2}u_\ell\varepsilon^{\ell jki}\omega_{jk}$, where $\varepsilon^{ijk\ell}$ is the Levi-Civita tensor (denoted by $\eta^{ijk\ell}$ in the book). Finnally $\overline{\omega^i{}_{;j}} := h^i{}_kh_j{}^\ell \omega^k{}_\ell$.

This equation $(A)$ is supposed to be derived from the Ricci identity for $u_i$, but due to a typo it is unclear to me exactly how. However, in attempting to reproduce it, I find that the right hand side should be zero. My attempt follows below.

From the definitions we have $h^i{}_jh_i{}^k = u_ju^k + \delta_j{}^k = h_j{}^k$, whence
$$
\overline{\omega^i{}_{;i}} = \omega^i{}_{;i} + u_iu^j\omega^i{}_{;j}.
$$
Choosing a co-moving frame we get $u_iu^j\omega^i{}_{;j} = \gamma^j{}_{ik}u_ju^k\omega^i = -\omega^i\dot{u}_i$, which is a generally covariant equation, whence
$$
\overline{\omega^i{}_{;i}} = \omega^i{}_{;i} - \omega^i\dot{u}_i. \tag{1}
$$
Also from the definition we have
$$
\omega^i{}_{;i} = -\frac{1}{2}\left(u_{\ell;i}\varepsilon^{\ell jki}\omega_{jk} + u_\ell\varepsilon^{\ell jki}\omega_{jk;i}\right),
$$
where we used the fact that the Levi-Civita tensor has vanishing covariant derivative. Now, since $u_{i;j} = \overline{u_{i;j}} - \dot{u}_iu_j$ we must have $u_{\ell;i}\varepsilon^{\ell jki}\omega_{jk} = -\dot{u}_\ell u_i\varepsilon^{\ell jki}\omega_{jk} = u_i\varepsilon^{ijk\ell}\omega_{jk}\dot{u}_\ell$, so
$$
\omega^i{}_{;i} = \omega^i\dot{u}_i - \frac{1}{2}u_\ell\varepsilon^{\ell jki}\omega_{jk;i} \tag{2}
$$

Finally, from the Ricci identity for $u_i$ ($u_{i;[jk]} = \frac{1}{2}R_{i\ell kj}u^\ell$) by contracting with $u_\ell\varepsilon^{\ell ijk}$ we get
$$
u_\ell\varepsilon^{\ell ijk}u_{i;[jk]} = \frac{1}{2}u_\ell\varepsilon^{\ell ijk}R_{imkj}u^m = \frac{1}{2}u_\ell\varepsilon^{\ell ijk}R_{mijk}u^m = 0,
$$
by the cyclic identity (first Bianchi identity), but $u_\ell\varepsilon^{\ell ijk}u_{i;[jk]} = u_\ell\varepsilon^{\ell ijk}u_{[i;j]k}$ and since the Levi-Civita tensor serves to project orthogonally we have $u_\ell\varepsilon^{\ell ijk}u_{i;[jk]} = u_\ell\varepsilon^{\ell ijk}\omega_{ij;k}$ whence
$$
u_\ell\varepsilon^{\ell ijk}\omega_{ij;k} = 0. \tag{3}
$$

Combining $(1)$, $(2)$, and $(3)$ we get
$$
\overline{\omega^i{}_{;i}} = 0. \tag{B}
$$

However, $(A)$ and $(B)$ certainly seem to be contradictory. Are they reconcilable or is either $(A)$ or $(B)$ wrong? I cannot seem to find any error in my calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was in the derivation of $(3)$, where I implicitly assumed that the projection operator has a vanishing covariant derivative, something that obviously is not true. Specifically, if one carries out the calculations, one gets
$$
\omega_{ij;k} = \dot{u}_{[i}u_{j];k} + 2u^\ell{}_{;k}\omega_{\ell[j}u_{i]} + h_i{}^\ell h_j{}^mu_{[\ell;m]k}.
$$
Upon contraction with $-\frac{1}{2}u_\ell\varepsilon^{\ell ijk}$ the middle term vanishes due to symmetries, and the projection operators in the last term become Kronecker deltas for the same reason and thus vanishes by the Ricci identity (i.e. my original argument), whence
$$
-\frac{1}{2}u_\ell\varepsilon^{\ell ijk}\omega_{ij;k} = -\frac{1}{2}u_\ell\varepsilon^{\ell ijk}\dot{u}_iu_{j;k} = \omega^i\dot{u}_i.\tag{4}
$$
Replacing $(3)$ in the OP with $(4)$ yields exactly $(A)$:
$$
\overline{\omega^i{}_{;i}} = \omega^i\dot{u}_i. \tag{A}
$$